# matplotlib subplot grids create two different canvas instead of one

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to follow this example to make a grid of subplot:

http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/line_styles.html

but my code plot the two rows of plots in two different canvass and not in a single canvas (the images are the correct one). Does anyone understand why?

this is an extract of my code:

```
alphas = [45, 75]
numalp = len(alphas)

angles = np.linspace(pi/12, pi/2, num=10)
numobs = len(angles)

axisNum = 0

for a in alphas:

          #[some operations]

          for obsangl in angles:

                       #[some operations]

                       axisNum += 1
                       axii = plt.subplot(numalp, numobs, axisNum)
                       plt.errorbar(g, Pgamma, yerr = ePgamma, color = 'green', fmt = '.')                
                       axii1 = axii.twinx()                
                       plt.plot(g, lightcurva, 'b-')
                       axii.set_yticklabels([])
                       axii.set_xticklabels([])                
                       axii1.set_yticklabels([])
                       axii1.set_xticklabels([])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `plt.figure()` in the `for a in alphas` loop? (Among your `#[some operations]`) If so, then for each time you call this you get a new figure, unless you specify a figure number. For example, the following will create two figures, each with one row:

```
for  a in alphas:
    fig=plt.figure()
    for obsangl in angles:
        # etc.
```

If this is the case, then to correct it you can define the figure before all the loops:

```
fig=plt.figure()
for a in alphas:
    for obsang1 in angles:
        # etc.
```

Or you can specify a figure number:

```
for  a in alphas:
    fig=plt.figure(1)  # Specifies Figure 1
    for obsangl in angles:
        # etc.
```